# Could the /tags API return minimal information about synonyms?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, api-v2, tags

It would be very helpful if the [`/tags` API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags) could provide at least a bare minimum of information about tag synonyms. Either:

- Number of synonyms the tag has, if any.
- Or a true/false flag for tags which have at least one synonym.

Sometimes you want to fetch stuff about tags including synonyms but since the two are somewhat separate, you may need to scan the complete sets of both tags and synonyms.

For instance if I use the `filter`/`inname` to get tags I'm interested in I would then see which have synonyms and then call the `/tags/synonyms` API for just those tags.

As it is I would have to call `/tags/synonyms` on the complete set of tags and check the `from-tag`/`to_tag` of each to find the ones I'm interested in, which is a lot less efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [tag object](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/tag) now has a `has_synonyms` field which is true when there's at least 1 approved synonym for a tag.